# Print GLPK objective/constraints in human readable format

Tags: debugging, linear-programming, human-readable, glpk

I'm using GLPK C API for a mixed integer programming problem. Is there some way to print the objective/constraints in human readable format for debugging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the nicest format is the [CPLEX LP format](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/CPLEX-format.htm). It looks something like this:

> Maximize
>   obj: x1 + 2 x2 + 3 x3 + x4
>   Subject To
>    c1: - x1 + x2 + x3 + 10 x4 <= 20
>    c2: x1 - 3 x2 + x3 <= 30
>    c3: x2 - 3.5 x4 = 0
>   Bounds
>    0 <= x1 <= 40
>    2 <= x4 <= 3
>   General
>    x4
>   End

You can write your model in this format by calling:

`int glp_write_lp(glp_prob *P, const glp_cpxcp *parm, const char *fname);`

See also ***`glp_write_lp` — write problem data in CPLEX LP format*** in the documentation that comes with GLPK.